# PHP: How to use more than 3 traits with same function name?I want to use all the same name functions

Tags: php

If I have two traits and both the traits use same name for a function

```
trait mytrait1{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function1';
  }
}
trait mytrait2{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function2';
  }
}

class ParentClass{
    public function parentfunction(){
        echo 'parent function';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    use mytrait1,mytrait2{
        mytrait1::triatfunction as  triatfunction1; 
        mytrait2::triatfunction as  triatfunction2;     
    }
    public function childfunction(){
        echo 'child function';
    }
}


$obj = new ChildClass();

$obj->parentfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->childfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction1();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction2();
```

> Fatal error: Trait method triatfunction has not been applied, because
>   there are collisions with other trait methods on ChildClass in

I am not able to use as keyword in the above code.

---

But if change

```
    use mytrait1,mytrait2{
        mytrait1::triatfunction as  triatfunction1; 
        mytrait2::triatfunction as  triatfunction2;     
    }
```

to

```
    use mytrait1,mytrait2{
        mytrait1::triatfunction insteadof mytrait2; 
        mytrait2::triatfunction as  triatfunction2;     
    }
```

and calling using

```
$obj->triatfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction2();
```

It works.

---

Now I have three traits with functions with same name.

How can I use all the three functions in all the different traits in my function

```
trait mytrait1{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function1';
  }
}
trait mytrait2{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function2';
  }
}
trait mytrait3{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function3';
  }
}

class ParentClass{
    public function parentfunction(){
        echo 'parent function';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    use mytrait1,mytrait2,mytrait3{
        mytrait1::triatfunction insteadof mytrait2; 
        mytrait2::triatfunction as traitfunction1;  
        mytrait3::triatfunction as  triatfunction2;     
    }
    public function childfunction(){
        echo 'child function';
    }
}


$obj = new ChildClass();

$obj->parentfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->childfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction1(); 
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction2();
```

Comment: this is a really backwards of doing things.. if both do the same thing, just create one generic class and pass parameters to further specify your needs?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs The above is an example code. In real code all the three functions may implement different things, and yes I know how to solve the problem with different approach.But the problem here how to use the trait in this situation.

Comment: by using properties of the class? I'm not sure why you'd break it up like this? it doesn't make logical sense to me .. ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I am just learning, and I am thinking of how to use the trait in this situation.

Comment: ah I see, well in my eyes.. you wouldn't? Maybe I've been too accustomed to MVC styled code, to me this seems really inefficient :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add to the `insteadof` all the traits you are replacing, not only part of them.

In your case you're only replacing `mytrait2`, but `mytrait3` still has the same function and the conflict is not resolved. The keyword `as` is creating an alias, but does not resolve the conflict.

If for example traits A, B, C, D have all the same method `someMethod`, you need to indicate that A replaces them all like:
`A::someMethod insteadof B, C, D;`

```
trait mytrait1{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function1';
  }
}
trait mytrait2{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function2';
  }
}
trait mytrait3{
  public function triatfunction(){
    echo 'trait function3';
  }
}

class ParentClass{
    public function parentfunction(){
        echo 'parent function';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    use mytrait1,mytrait2,mytrait3{
        mytrait1::triatfunction insteadof mytrait2, mytrait3; 
        mytrait2::triatfunction as triatfunction1;  
        mytrait3::triatfunction as triatfunction2;     
    }
    public function childfunction(){
        echo 'child function';
    }
}


$obj = new ChildClass();

$obj->parentfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->childfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction();
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction1(); 
echo '<br>';
$obj->triatfunction2();
```

Comment: throws Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ChildClass::triatfunction1()

Comment: Well that's a typo in the method name, didn't see that, let me edit it. Check now :)

Comment: what was the typo

Comment: it was aliased to traitfunction1, not triatfunction1